# How do I merge the values of these ImmutableJS Records

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I have what seems to be like two identical data structures, created with normalizr from the API, and ImmutableJS Records.

You can see the console logged, stringified data structures below, the top being the response from normalizr and the bottom the current state in my store.

[image: Console Log state]

**I can see that the response in keyed numerically and my Report map is not, I have a feeling this is the issue why my two data sets are not merging.** Here's my code:

```
  fromJS(newState).map(
    (entity, key) => {
      switch (key) {
        case "entity":
        return state.merge(
          state.mergeIn(['entity'],entity.get('0'))
        )
        default:
        return state
      }
    }
  )
```

I'm using to `entity.get('0')` to overcome the keyed issue, just to show that the merge will work before I `.map()` over them, but the merger is not happening and I'm being turned the old state.

My Entity Record looks like this:

```
const EntityRecord = Record({
  id: 0,
  status: "",
  messages: [],
  redirectTo: "",
  entityType: "",
  isFetching: false,
  lang: "",
  title: "",
  charset: "",
  viewport: "",
  description: "",
  keywords: "",
  forms: [],
  socialLoginText: "",
  forgotPasswordLinkText: "",
  registerLinkText: ""
});
```

Help and guidance much appreciated, thank you!